# How to install OpenSUSE 13.2 OS over Elementary OS without loss of Windows 7 partition?

Tags: software-installation, system-installation, elementary-os

I have a laptop which contains Elementary OS Luna and Windows 7 on separate partitions.
I want to install OpenSUSE 13.2 over the existing Elementary OS.

Is there an option in Open SUSE that allows over writing/installing over the Elementary OS partition only. I just want other things to be the same (windows 7 partition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSUSE provides all the expected options in the installation wizard to remove the partitions you wish (your Elementary OS partitions) and to leave the Windows partitions in place and to create the necessary partions for OpenSUSE in the space made available by deleting the Elementry OS partitions.  You should create your new partition setup from scratch.  When you come to the partitioning screen, click the button "Create Partition Setup" and manage your partitions manually instead of allowing the system to make a proposal.  I dual boot Windows 8.1 and OpenSuse 13.2 and that is how I set things up.  If you are going to install using UEFI, try this link and follow the instructions in the second post: https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/501833-Windows-8-1-Dual-Boot-Install-Advice